# Formatting function with similar signature to print function

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have some code that prints stuff to console using some of the `print` function's capabilities, e.g.

```
print('name'.ljust(44), 'age'.rjust(4), 'idea'.rjust(8), sep=',')
for name, age, idea in items:    
    print(name.ljust(44), str(age).rjust(4), idea.rjust(8), sep=',')
```

In other cases I will use the `end` parameter to write multiple strings to a single line, i.e.

```
print('hello ', end='')
print('world!')
```

My question is how could I most easily write this `print` formatted output to a stream, a file, or even better just collect into a single string object? If I revert to regular string formatting the syntax will be different and I'll need to re-write all my formatting.

Comment: What's wrong with `print()`?  It takes an optional `file=` parameter, that can specify a file or file-like object (such as `StringIO` to collect into a string).  If you don't want to modify all your `print`s to add this parameter, you can temporarily replace `sys.stdout` with the file or file-like object.

Comment: @jasonharper then that's the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO) allows you to use a string as if it were a file. Along with using `print(..., file=...)` you can then do:

```
import io

with io.StringIO() as fp:
    print("hi", "mom", sep=" ", file=fp)
    print('hello ', end='', file=fp)
    print('world!', file=fp)

    str = fp.getvalue()

print(str)
```

which gives

```
hi mom
hello world!
```

as (I think) you want. You can also use `fp.readlines()` if you want a list of strings for each line.

You can also use a [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#module-tempfile) which may use the filesystem (but may not), with almost identical syntax:

```
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode="w+") as fp:
    print("hi", "mom", sep=" ", file=fp)
    print('hello ', end='', file=fp)
    print('world!', file=fp)

    fp.seek(0)
    str = fp.read()

print(str)
```

You do need to specify the `mode` as the default gives a binary file which doesn't let you `print`, and explicitly rewind back to the beginning before reading. (FWIW, an earlier version of my answer had `flush=True` for each `print` but I don't think that's needed.)

Answer (score 0):

Does pickle help you out?

Something like

```
import pickle

text = "Hallo welt          Test."

with open('parrot.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(text, f)


with open('parrot.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    print(pickle.load(f))
```

Comment: It might if I could easily print to the pickle file. Probably is that I don't have a variable like your `text` that simply contains all the text.